# Managing a Comic-Like Project in Blender

Tags: scene

i'm currently working on a Comic-like Project with Blender. I currently create every Page as a Scene in Blender, render it, do the stuff with Photoshop and done.

But now, in my newest Project, only the Base Scene is about 500MB and takes 22GB RAM (got 64GB so not that a big issue) to open. The real Problem is, i run out of VRAM almost every time i want to Render. I have a RTX4090 with 24GB of VRAM. (This is only an Issue when using Viewport Render or Material Preview even *once*)

So duplicating the Scene for each Page, modifiying it... is not an option. Which was my current workflow. (Maybe doing an incremental save every once in a while and deleting already-done scenes from the new File)

I though about doing it with Keyframes, which is only partly working as i need to make changes to the meshes in between pages/scenes.

Anyone got an Idea on how to Manage a Project like this?
( Currently ~30 Pages planned )